# Need to change default poll submit message in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

We are using the poll module and need to override poll default message.

Basically we try with stringoverride module and also use inside the `hook_form_alter`, used `drupal_get_messages()` function but not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the submit callback using the "hook_form_alter" hook to define your own callback :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'poll_view_voting') {
    $form['vote']['#submit'] = array('_my_poll_submit');
  }
}
```

then you copy paste the code from the "poll_vote" function (in the "poll.module" file) in your callback function and you change the message as needed:

```
function _my_poll_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
  //etc ...
  //and at the end:
  drupal_set_message(t('My text for your vote was recorded.'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This module will help you to override string messages.

https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides

Regards.

Comment: We used that, here trying "Your vote was recorded" to override but not working. rest of string is override properly.

Comment: Y read an article that says ajax poll module does not show this message. Could you try it? http://drupal.org/project/ajax_poll